# Express API is not getting called from react.js

Tags: node.js, api, express

Hi everyone facing issue for API not getting called from node(express.js).

When i call it using controller file it returns status 200 with data=[] empty array and does not print in console ' [] ' but when i call the same API in the product.js(API file) it gets called
gives response as status 200 and data=hi
i have disabled **app.disable("etag");** in app.js

Calling Api from react.js to Express.js API

```
export const getRandomProductAPI = () => Axios.get(`${url}/v1/product/getRandomProduct`);
```

I am having API folder in which i am reciving the request from react.js in Product.js(API file).

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const productController = require("../controllers/ProductController");

const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callBack) {
    callBack(null, "");
  },
});

const uploadProduct = multer({ storage }).single("productImage");
const updateProduct = multer({ storage }).single("newEditImage");

// router.get("/getRandomProduct", (req, res) => {
//   res.status(200).send("hi");
// });

router.post("/add", uploadProduct, productController.addProduct);
router.get("/:category", productController.getProduct);
router.delete("/:id/:imageName", productController.deleteProduct);
router.patch("/", updateProduct, productController.updateProduct);
router.get("/Id", productController.getLatestProductId);
router.get("/getRandomProduct", productController.getRandomProduct);

module.exports = router;
```

API which is got called is the last one-> **router.get("/getRandomProduct",roductController.getRandomProduct);**
Controller Code ProductController.js

```
const getRandomProduct = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("called");
  res.status(200).send("hi");
 };

module.exports = {
  addProduct,
  getProduct,
  deleteProduct,
  updateProduct,
  getLatestProductId,
  getRandomProduct,
};
```

**App.js code**

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

require("dotenv").config();

const middlewares = require("./middlewares");
const api = require("./api");

const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
}

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
// app.disable("etag");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: " Furnitures ",
  });
});

app.use("/v1", api);

app.use(middlewares.notFound);
app.use(middlewares.errorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you mention both the calls and which one is the problem? The question is unclear

Comment: When called Axios.get(`${url}/v1/product/getRandomProduct`); API from react it should call-> router.get("/getRandomProduct", productController.getRandomProduct);  method, it is not calling and insted it returns 200 status with empty array " getRandomProduct " method is not called.

Comment: Can you edit the question with app.js code as well?

Comment: Added code for App.js

Comment: I don't think you have put `/product/` in the route for your express app.  Try `app.use("/v1/product", api)` in place of `app.use("/v1", api)`.

Comment: I am having an index.js file were i have defined the " /product " for API route. Initialy when i was calling this API i was getting statue " 304 " then i disabeled app.disable("etag");.